# How to provide the getData() response with nested JSON data?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, looker-studio, google-apps-script-api

I'm not able to model a nested JSON data in Google Data Studio. I have the problem exactly in the ***"addresses"*** field.

#### The JSON Data:

---

```js
{
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 37314,
            "first_name": "Lio",
            "last_name": "Mino",
            "addresses": [
                {
                    "id": 7834,
                    "city": "Washington",
                    "primary": 1,
                },
                {
                    "id": 5034,
                    "city": "New yourk",
                    "primary": 1,
                }
             ]
         },
           ...
      ]
}
```

Without the *`addresses`* field all work fine. But i need to returned addresses also.
I hope I explained the situation well.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getAddresses() {
  const s = '{"data":[{"id":37314,"first_name":"Lio","last_name":"Mino","addresses":[{"id":7834,"city":"Washington","primary":1},{"id":5034,"city":"Newyourk","primary":1}]}]}';
  const obj = JSON.parse(s);
  const o=obj.data.map(e=>{return e.addresses.map(a=>{return a})});
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(o))
}

Execution log
6:45:15 PM  Notice  Execution started
6:45:15 PM  Info    [[{"id":7834,"city":"Washington","primary":1},{"id":5034,"city":"Newyourk","primary":1}]]
6:45:15 PM  Notice  Execution completed
```

Comment: I understand what you did, and thank you in advance. But i'm not able to see how that can help me in the getData() function.let me clarify more:
the getData() response is like :
`return {
    schema: requestedFields.build(),
    rows: rows
  };`

The question is how to model the rows since i have nested JSON data?

Comment: Yeah I don’t know what you’re talking about what do you mean by model what is it that you want to do